# Deleting 'node_modules' folder but it is regenerated after a little while

Tags: node.js, npm

After `npm install`, I get a folder named `node_modules` created.

When I cleanup my project (via GIT clean) this folder is deleted, but then recreated some time afterwards.

Looking inside it, I see:

```
node_modules
    scrypt
        build
            Release
                obj
                    copied_files
                        copied_files.tlog
                            link-VCTIP.delete.64.tlog
                            link-VCTIP.read.64.tlog
                            link-VCTIP.write.64.tlog
```

I guess that either `node` or `npm` are responsible for this.

Why is it happening, and how can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

`scrypt` is a native node/io C++ wrapper for Colin Percival's scrypt cryptographic hash utility.

Maybe you should not delete it.

emmm....I'm not sure

Comment: add more description to answer.